# Cython and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I am trying to Cython to speed up some class. But I still want the code to run in pure Python too.

How do I define an array in an class (code has been simplified)

```
import cython

class A:
    def __init__(self):


        if cython.compiled:

            # This will work in Cython
            for k in len(self.S):
               self.S[k]=k

        else:
            # This will work in interpreter
            self.S=range(8)

    def test(self):
         self.S[0]+=1
```

And in the .pxd:

```
 import cython

 cdef class A
     cdef int[8] S

     cdef test(self)
```

But Cython complains on compilation:

```
Cannot convert Python object to 'int [8]'
```

Comment: Just a comment, not directly related to your question, but if you want the `cython-compiled` part to fully take advantage of Cython's speedup, you should always `cdef` your increment variables as well: `cdef k`...

Comment: My goal was to speed up the test method. which (is in the un simplified version is more complex) is called millions of times, while __init__ is only called once,

Comment: Sure, I got that. That was a very general remark targeting other people who are susceptible to read this thread. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work:

```
import array

class A:
    def __init__(self):

        # This will work in Cython
        self.S=array.array("l", range(8))

    def test(self):
         self.S[0]+=1
```

And .pxd:

```
cimport cpython.array

cdef class RC4:
    cdef int [:] S
    cdef int test(self)
```

Comment: The second function should be test(), not next().

Answer (score 0):

This is because the syntax is wrong, more like:

```
cdef int S[8]
```

Also, there's no need to `import cython`.

This is actually defined in the very beginning of the [documentation for cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#ctypedef).

Comment: Nope. The error message does not change. The problem seems to be, that I must somehow initialize self.S in pure Python without causing  a type conflict during compile (or for Cython to ignore the else case). My code worked without the CPython initializer in Cython

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck Try creating a separate file, where the only thing you do is make a `cdef int S[8]`, and see if cython can recognize that, since I'm 100% sure that the above syntax is correct.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck My advice is to keep cython completely separate from Python, and just import the functions or classes that you require. I say this because cython has many quirks and most of them come from when you try to use them together too much. Also you might try using `cpdef` instead of `cdef`.

Comment: That is what I did with the .pxd file. My Problem is that I habe statementwhich initializes S in pure Python. And when I try so (conditionally) Cython refuses to compile.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck Thats to be expected. I'm sorry that you can't have what you want. To be honest, I also discourage writing apps in pure cython (my own experience), its better to write them in C/C++, and then import them _into_ cython (to wrap them). I say this from experience because, cython has many quirks I'm afraid.

Comment: I mean in this case you're initializing a C array, in in Python its a C array, you can't just change it to something else. It does not inherit from the generic python object, its statically typed.